# Generate report via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to get the report like this from my database tables.

[image: report]

Things should consider when making the report are :

1. report will generate based on the selected date.
2. two database and two tables ( already joined ) 'showroom' and 'customer'
3. showroom have showroom_name and each have related records in customer
   table. One showroom may have several customer enquiry in each days.
4. In a single day may have number of enquiry from each showroom.
5. Let's say if the first day of a month 5 enquiries it should be appear
   under the date column and in front of the specific showroom name.

my query to select the data from two tables are works fine.

```
SELECT
    abans_crm.customers.added_date,
    abans_crm.customers.location_id
    FROM
    abans_crm.customers
    INNER JOIN sh_sso.showrooms ON sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_id = abans_crm.customers.location_id
    WHERE
    abans_crm.customers.added_location = -99 AND
    abans_crm.customers.type_id = 1
    ORDER BY
    abans_crm.customers.location_id ASC
```

**Query result is**

[image: query result]

Which i was marked two data have two different dates. 2016-02-09 and 2016-02-23.
'356' is the showroom_id so day 9 column of the report become 1 and day 23 column become 1. hope you get my point. How could i count each showroom number of enquiry ?

**Hers the code snippet which i have write so far. don't know to write afterwards**

```
<?php 
                              
echo $row->showroom_name;
  
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Sate11it@') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  
mysql_select_db('sh_sso', $conn); 
mysql_select_db('abans_crm', $conn);
  
$query_3 = "SELECT
                abans_crm.customers.added_date,
                abans_crm.customers.location_id
                FROM
                abans_crm.customers
                INNER JOIN sh_sso.showrooms 
                ON sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_id = abans_crm.customers.location_id
                WHERE
                abans_crm.customers.added_location = -99 AND
                abans_crm.customers.type_id = 1
                ORDER BY
                abans_crm.customers.location_id ASC";
                  
$retval = mysql_query($query_3);
                                                    
if(!$retval ) {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

$select_month = '2';                                   
$select_year = '2016'; 

$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$select_month,$select_year);

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
                        
    $year = date('Y',strtotime($row2['added_date']));
    $month = date('m',strtotime($row2['added_date']));
    $date = date('m',strtotime($row2['added_date']));
                        
    $showroom_id = $row2['location_id'];
                       
    if($year == $select_year && $month == $select_month){
      
        for($a = 1; $a <= $days; $a++){
           echo "<td id=".$a.">".$count."</td>"; 
        }

    }
 }
?>
```

if you need more details please comment below.

**customer table fields**
`cu_id`, `cu_name`, `cu_email`, `cu_address`, `cu_phone`, `cu_remark`, `added_date`, `last_update`, `added_by`, `status_id`, `location_id`, `cu_nic`, `cu_age`, `cu_occ`, `cu_land`, `purchase_type`, `pref_model`, `pref_color`, `oth_model`, `purchase_date`, `currenrt_bike`, `bike_year`, `att_by`, `cu_made`, `about_hero`, `source_id`, `added_ip`, `dealer_flag`, `added_location`, `cur_milage`, `cat_id`, `type_id`

**showroom table fields**
`showroom_id`, `showroom_code`, `showroom_name`, `showroom_address`, `address_city`, `manager_name`, `manager_mobile`, `manager_id`, `shop_email`, `shop_phone`, `shop_fax`, `showroom_type`, `added_date`, `last_update`, `added_by`, `status_id`, `level_id`

Thank you.

Comment: if provide an sql fiddle with your question it is easier for us to try stuff:
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Add date to your ORDER BY clause. The rest would be done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT DATE(abans_crm.customers.added_date) AS new_added_date
       COUNT(DATE(abans_crm.customers.added_date)) AS customer_amount,
       abans_crm.customers.location_id
FROM abans_crm.customers
INNER JOIN sh_sso.showrooms ON sh_sso.showrooms.showroom_id = abans_crm.customers.location_id
WHERE abans_crm.customers.added_location = -99 
AND abans_crm.customers.type_id = 1
GROUP BY abans_crm.customers.location_id, new_added_date
ORDER BY abans_crm.customers.location_id ASC, new_added_date ASC
```

We use `DATE` to only get the year, month, day part.
We then `GROUP BY` both `location_id` as well as `new_added_date`, this way results will only get grouped if the year, month and day are the same.
I also added an `ORDER BY` on `new_added_date`, might not be neccesary